# Javascript View HTML Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a wysiwyg editor because most of the ones I have found do not work the way I would like them to.

I have most of it done, "bold, Italic, Forecolor, backcolor, etc" but the problem I am having now is the make a **view code** button.

What I would like to happen is when the user hits the button they see the code and if they hit it again it toggles back to html.

I have tried

```
$('#wysiwyg').text($('#wysiwyg').html());
```

It did exactly what I wanted but it did not keep the line breaks, so all of the `<p>` tags would run together across one line. Does anyone have a better solution that would keep the line breaks, so if there is a line break for the `<p>` like there if you viewed the html.

Comment: Have you tried to put css style white-space: pre; when you switch to view code mode? (changed to correct name of css property)

Comment: Do you mean instead of doing the code snippet above or after. I have tried wrapping the html in a pre after, but that dont yeild any different results. becuase once you so the text like this it seems to remove the line breaks.

Comment: That is just a css property which force element to show line breaks `as-is`. Without it, line breaks (`\r\n`) are ignored in HTML.

Comment: I realized what I did wrong. I just went back and re-tried this and realized I didnt use the "dash". This works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `white-space:pre` when you switch to **view code** mode.
That should work fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/rNPJA/

Solution code showing how to toggle between the two

```
if ($(this).data('wysiwyg-action') == "changeview") 
  if ($('#wysiwyg').css('white-space') != "pre")
    $('#wysiwyg').text($('#wysihtml-content').html()).css({ 'white-space':'pre' })
  else
    $('#wysiwyg').html($('#wysihtml-content').text()).css({ 'white-space':'normal' })
```

Comment: Just wanted to show people how to do this little snippet in case they come across this thread in the future.